# Can links to target sites' FAQs be added to the new migration dialog?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, migration

In the migration window, a link to a target site's FAQ page would be more useful than a link to the site itself. This would give closers a better idea of whether the question would be acceptable on the target site.

Given that the base "off topic" option has a link that points to the current's site's FAQ page, this would be consistent. It's also more important with more sites coming out of beta and being added to the close dialog.

Any thoughts on this from the dev team?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I converted the "migrate to.." target links from:

`baseurl`

to:

`baseurl + /faq`

Comment: This has reverted back to just `baseurl`. So it's not `[status-completed]` any more.

Comment: @ChrisF this was my bad - the close dialog was refactored and I left that off. Next push will fix it.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with this. Superusers are already complaining about off-topic migrations! Take a look [here](https://meta.superuser.com/q/1515/36601).

Comment: Ha! - that's where I originally suggested having a link to the target site's faq!

Comment: SUers have *always* complained about this. I've read their FAQ and I *still* don't know what's on-topic there; I just flip a coin when migrating now.

Comment: @Shog9 Then why migrate? Vote to close as off-topic HERE and that's it. This way you are harming SO user who is sent to SU just to be told to go away and you are harming SU community which needs to close off-topic questions instead of helping people with on-topic questions. We've had programming related questions which were migrated from SO to SU and then back to SO! The fact that SU users have always complained DOES NOT make it any less true  and is a logical fallacy. I'm being a bit harsh now, but such action can be considered spamming.

Comment: @Shog9  Furthermore, as far as I can see, you don't even have a SU account. What then makes you competent to decide when to migrate questions there? You admitted that you don't know what questions are on-topic and what questions are off-topic.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: I've had a SU account since it was created, and I've watched it change from "The place for all those computer questions folks keep asking on SO" to... whatever it is now. The reason for migration is always the same: as a courtesy to the asker, we direct him to a more appropriate venue rather than merely closing his question and telling him to go away. This works best when the destination has a clearly-defined topic.

Comment: @Shog9 Sorry, I couldn't find your SU account. Still, SU does have a clearly defined topic. Most of the migrated questions fail the "is not about" part which is very clear.

Comment: @shog9 what are you, forrest gump? it's not that hard to figure out what is disallowed on SU: stuff that goes on gaming and webapps, and of course shopping recommendations..

Answer (score 1):

The close dialog has reverted to just having the base url as the link.

Can `/faq` (as detailed in Jeff's answer) be readded.

(Having to answer as I can't edit my question).