# Show topic information in migration dialog

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, migration, close-dialog

When we close as "belongs to another site", that is migrate, we have to know (or guess) the appropriate target site.

Please use the empty space and show the content of the selected target site's `help/on-topic` so it is easier to check whether the chosen site is an appropriate target.

A [similar concern](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67625/can-links-to-target-sites-faqs-be-added-to-the-new-migration-dialog) has been raised before, but I don't even see that link in the dialog where any site can be entered.

Comment: It would be better if folks took a few moments to familiarize themselves with the available migration targets (there aren't that many available ones).  Reading Help/On Topic at time of migration seems a bit top-heavy as a workflow, and Help/On Topic doesn't always capture the essence of the community gestalt.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: a) As mod (and 10k?) I can pick *any* site as target. (On beta sites, we don't even have the curated list for everybody, iirc.) b) "You should already know that" is a weak argument against "Here, let me show you". c) If help/on-topic does not fit the site, it needs to be rewritten.

Comment: I certainly have no objection to providing a link to that material.  I just don't expect people to read it before voting to migrate.