# Display site description for migration targets on the moderator "belongs on another site" dialog

Tags: feature-request, migration, moderator-tools

When I want to migrate a question, I get this dialog:

[image: migration dialog, showing description for predefined target but nothing for alternate site]

Unfortunately there no description of the site or its scope at all, only its name. Something like this, for example, would be a lot better:

[image: mock-up of a description shown for a free-form entry]

In the case of the Android site, the scope is rather unexpected. I, for one, would have simply assumed that Android programming questions would be on-topic there.

Given that there are now 150 sites (and growing), it is difficult to be familiar with the scope of them all. Yes, I could go to the site and check the scope, and that's certainly something I would do in case of doubt, but just making the wrong assumption about a site's scope is an easy thing to do, and can be fixed with one or two lines of description. Right now there is no context *at all*. Not even a link to the site; I even have to figure out the domain name by myself.

Note: this question/request was provoked by a discussion in the teacher's lounge prompted by confusion over the scope of Android Stack Exchange.

Comment: Somewhat related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67625/can-links-to-target-sites-faqs-be-added-to-the-new-migration-dialog - having the link to the selected target's "what on topic" page would also help.

Comment: But why do you want to migrate if you're not deeply familiar with the destination site? Are you not trying to bypass the requirements detailed in [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/286110) by asking a technical solution for something which shouldn't be there at first place? I recommend closing the question as usual and that's all. You can always suggest OP to check the help center of the site where you think the question might be on-topic and if they find it on-topic then they should ask it there. Your job is done at that point. // Did I overlook something?

Comment: Not all questions need to live somewhere. They don't need to be migrated if you don't know where they should go without already knowing the site from its name alone and just closed

Comment: Unfortunately, recent events suggest other opinions. So it would be helpful having a one-liner to keep them down. That one-liner might be setup (as default) by the "target site" (e.g. Android.SE could have "End-users only – NO DEV STUFF, please!"), with the "migrating site" being able to edit that when adding/having the site listed with their "primary migration targets".

Comment: Then stop being lazy about the other sites you're dumping crap on. Understand what they're on about and then decide and not just because the name is a trigger

Comment: @random Thanks, that's just what ASE was complaining about (being dumped all that without second thoughts). Which is why we brought it up on TL originally. To the point, and I cannot agree more: **"decide […] not just because the name is a trigger"** – which is what those comments requested here can help with (avoiding such associations).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256149/162102 -- this question arises from moderators who are *trying to do the right thing* (review the other site's scope before migrating), which is more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @Firelord Well "this is not how people are supposed to use it, so no change is needed" is not a very constructive attitude. People *are* using it like this, whether they are *supposed to* is not really important, as such.

Comment: I think this would be quite beneficial.  Virtually none of the migrations ASE receives are well-thought-out, they just see the word "Android" and migrate.  A basic "X is off-topic" might help cut down on the number of those that we end up rejecting.